# SQL Server 2005 Small Business vs SQL Server Express 2012

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, sql-server-express

Our office server is running a SQL Server 2005 Small Business which does not do much other than stay idle. We are putting a small database on it - a million or two rows total.

Is there any benefit to installing SQL Server 2012 Express over using existing software for a DB this size? Hardware is decent Dell Xeon, only a couple years old.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500435%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) site shows the differences between SQL Server 2005 and 2008, and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500435.aspx) site shows the differences between 2008 and 2012.

It all depends on what you're going to be using SQL Server for, but if its just a backup database, you probably don't need to upgrade.